# date format in DDMonYY in fortran

Tags: fortran

I want to know if there is any intrinsic function which converts date to DDMonYY format in fortran.
As I know Idate returns a date in DDMMYYY.But I would like to know how to get date format in DDMonYY.Do I need to write a separate program which extracts month from Idate and writes character equivalent (like 1 for Jan)

Answer (score 2):

There is the [DATE_AND_TIME](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DATE_005fAND_005fTIME.html) intrinsic which can return the information you want, with the exception that you get the month as a numeric value in the second element of the VALUES argument. It should then be quite easy to use that month number as the index into a character array with the (3 letter) month names.

Comment: Or, instead of the `select` statement, use the month as an index for an array of strings.

Comment: @eriktous: Doh, that is of course a simpler choice. :) Answer updated.

Comment: It just reminded me of an old article on The Daily WTF I happened to read last week or so: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Switched_on_Loops.aspx ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a routine that does what you want and a quick program that tests it:

```
PROGRAM date_test

  CHARACTER(len=7) :: date

  CALL get_DDMonYY(date)

  PRINT*, date

CONTAINS

  SUBROUTINE get_DDMonYY(date)
    CHARACTER(len=7), INTENT(out) :: date

    CHARACTER(len=2) :: dd
    CHARACTER(len=3) :: mons(12)
    CHARACTER(len=4) :: yyyy
    INTEGER :: values(8)

    mons = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',&
      'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

    CALL DATE_AND_TIME(VALUES=values)

    WRITE(  dd,'(i2)') values(3)
    WRITE(yyyy,'(i4)') values(1)

    date = dd//mons(values(2))//yyyy(3:4)
  END SUBROUTINE get_DDMonYY

END PROGRAM date_test
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no such intrinsic, but it is not at all difficult to write an own subroutine to do that. You Just need to use something as

```
 write(mydate(3:5),fmt='(a3)') 'Jan'
```

where mydate is the character which will contain DDMonYY.

Comment: hey Could you pls tell me which fortran intrinsic function gets a date in format as ddMonYYY,eg 30Nov11?

Comment: There is none, you have to use date_and_time and use similer code as i wrote above in a case select or if construct.